# KOMA script: Completely remove space above chapter title

Tags: spacing, koma-script, chapters, titles

I use the KOMA script class scrreprt wit xelatex. Now, due to a strict template I need to set chapter titles exactly at the top of the page.

Here I found some recommendations https://komascript.de/node/179?destination=node/179. I tried two approaches but `\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=0pt]{chapter}` leaves some space while `\renewcommand*{\chapterheadstartvskip}{\vspace*{-\topskip}}` removes to much space. It seems like the line spacing also has an influence as well but it doesn't work even with the default spacing.

The following figure shows the results compared to a section title which is placed correctly. Hopefully anyone has an idea how to fix this.

[image: Chapter title not exactly at the top]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[
a4paper,
10pt,
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{footnotebackref}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}

\setmainfont[BoldFont={Verdanab.ttf},ItalicFont={Verdanai.ttf}]{Verdana.ttf}
\geometry{
    landscape=false,
    left=30mm,
    right=25mm,
    top=25mm,
    bottom=25mm,
}
\spacing{1.5}

\setkomafont{chapter}{\Large\normalfont\bfseries\MakeUppercase}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=0pt]{chapter} % Leaves some space above
\renewcommand*{\chapterheadstartvskip}{\vspace*{-\topskip}} % Violates top margin

\begin{document}

\chapter{Remaining space above chapter title õö}

\clearpage

\section{Section title is placed exactly at the top ÕÖ}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Well the section is not perfect: the accents are above the line. This shows that there is no exact value here, it depends on the letters used in the text. topskip is normally 10pt, so simply try out \vspace{-8pt} or other values until you get a pleasing result (and check with various titles).

Comment: Sorry, it is caused by not zooming in. If I take a closer look at the section title, it is exactly at the top and not above. So basically if it works for sections why is there a problem with chapters?

Comment: chapter probably contains an additional \strut which forces an uniform spacing. You wouldn't want one chapter a bit higher then the other.

Comment: So -8pt works fine for latin letters and I can life with accents placed a little bit higher. Thanks!

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I need to come back to this as I have noticed some unwanted bookmark behaviour when using the `hyperref` package. I dont want to open a new question as it seems to fit in this topic. I found out following spacing for the chapter headings:`\renewcommand*{\chapterheadstartvskip}{\vspace*{-\topskip+2pt}}`. Normally, when I zoom in and click on bookmarks, a small white area remains above the headings. But with this setting, I have no white space above it. The maximum is the top margin. Is there any way to change this as well (only for chapters)?

Comment: Ask a new question so that everyone see it. I'm not your personal support.